# Remove the inner object reference

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object

Hi all i have below object structure like as below

```
{
   "glazingSimpleMaterial":{
      "name":"Test",
      "solarName":"Test1"
   }
}
```

I would like to remove the "glazingSimpleMaterial" from that object and directly assign `name` and `solarName`  to draftlibrary (i.e) looking for this kind of structure

```
{
   "name":"Test",
   "solarName":"Test1"
}
```

I am getting the data here in below function

```
  const values = cloneDeep(originalValues);  
  // here the values are having initial data structure and need to do that and return the values
    
  return values;
```

Could any one please let me know how can i achieve the defined structure, Many thanks in advance

Comment: only `glazingSimpleMaterial` or even other properties of the same?

Comment: that object only having `glazingSimpleMaterial` as inner object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could spread `glazingSimpleMaterial` and remove that prop

```js
const originalValues = {
  "glazingSimpleMaterial": {
    "name": "Test",
    "solarName": "Test1"
  },
  "other": "other",
  "another": "another"
}

const modify = (originalValues) => {
  const res = { ...originalValues, ...originalValues["glazingSimpleMaterial"] }
  delete res["glazingSimpleMaterial"]
  return res
}

const res = modify(originalValues);

console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on the code that you have provided there are two ways to do that:

1. Assuming there are no other keys in the outer json (none mentioned in the OP question)
   Return only `glazingSimpleMaterial` from your function:

   ```
   function  getJson() {
     const values = cloneDeep(originalValues);  
     return values.glazingSimpleMaterial;
   }
   ```
2. Assuming there is more data in the main json: Move the data from `glazingSimpleMaterial` to the outer json, then delete `glazingSimpleMaterial` from it and return the json.

   ```
   function  getJson() {
     const values = cloneDeep(originalValues);  
     //optionally use a loop to copy values
     values["name"] =  values.glazingSimpleMaterial["name"];
     values["solarName"] =  values.glazingSimpleMaterial["solarName"];
     delete values.glazingSimpleMaterial;
     return values;
   }
   ```